# giving alias to sql result

Tags: mysql, join

i made this query that interacts with two tables but i have a problem fetching the data since both tables share the same field names.

```
SELECT * FROM `data` d JOIN `ans` a ON d.id=a.id AND d.id=2987
```

the result is:

```
id  nick      msg        time     ip    time_updated    id  nick    msg     time    ip
```

how can i make it to look like this?

```
a.id    a.nick    a.msg          a.time       a.ip  a.time_updated  b.id    b.nick  b.msg   b.time  b.ip
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to name each field specifically to do this.

```
SELECT a.id AS 'a.id', a.nick AS 'a.nick', ... FROM `data` d JOIN `ans` a ON d.id=a.id AND d.id=2987
```

Comment: In general, you don't want to `SELECT *` anyways. It's usually better (faster, less bandwidth) to pick the data you actually need.

Answer (score 3):

you need to give alias also to fields:

```
SELECT a.id AS a_id, b.id AS b_id ....
```